# Equivalent statements for differentiability of a function

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Can someone explain or help me find information about the second of these two equivalent statements presented in my calculus class? I could not find a proof for that in my textbook.

$ K \subset \mathbb{R} $. Let $ y \in K$, $f: K \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Then the following is equivalent

a) $f$ is differentiable at $y$

b) there exists a function $g: K \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ continuous at y, such that $ f(x) = f(y) + g(x)(x-y)$ for $x \in K$

On a side note, does this reasoning still hold for functions of more than one variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\Rightarrow$:

Let $f$ be differentiable at $y$.

Then set $g:K\to\mathbb{R}$, $g(x)=\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}$.

Why is $g$ continuous at $y$?

We have to check if $\lim_{x\downarrow y} g(x)=\lim_{x\uparrow y} g(x)$.

But this $f$ is differentiable at $y$, what is exactly what we are supposed to show!

$\Leftarrow$:

We need to show that $f$ is differentiable at $y$. Hence

$\lim_{x\to y} \frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}$ exists. It is

$\lim_{x\to y} \frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}=\lim_{x\to y} \frac{f(y)+g(x)(x-y)-f(y)}{x-y}=\lim_{x\to y} g(x)=g(y)$ since $g$ is continuous at $y$. So the limit exists.